# Django Form Validation overwrite email

Tags: django, forms, error-handling

I have the following form:

```
class RemoveEmail(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.CharField(label=_("E-Mail"), max_length=150,
                             error_messages={
                                 'invalid': _("Required. This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                                              "@_-.")})

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(forms.ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for f in self.fields:
            self.fields[f].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    def clean_email(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['email']

    def delete(self, commit=False):
        try:
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            newsletter = Newsletter.objects.get(email=email)
            newsletter.optout = True
            if commit:
                newsletter.save()
            return True
        except Newsletter.DoesNotExist:
            return False
```

Which is supposed to remove a user from the newsletter list. The user is identified by the e-mail.

Unfortunately, when the user submits the form it does not validate, but instead throws the error:

"Newsletter with this Email already exists."

Is there anyway to override this ? It seems like that the form things I want to create a new object, rather than change an existing one.

My View:

```
def optout(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = RemoveEmail(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            status = form.delete(True)
            return render(request, 'index/sad.html')
    else:
        form = RemoveEmail()

    context.update({'form': form})
    return render(request, 'index/optout.html', context)
```

My Model:

```
class Newsletter(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    optout = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    signup_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    useragent = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ipaddress = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    referrer = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `ModelForm` for this task.  Inherit from the regular `Form`:

```
class RemoveEmail(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-Mail"), max_length=150)
    ...
```